# Refreshing or re-running a class in Python 2.7

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, class, configuration

I have a class that retrieves values from a configuration file and a function that adds them. I call the class, change values then run the function to write them. When I call the class afterwards the values are not updated. I check the config file and the values have changed. Is there a way to get it to re-read the data every time I call it?

Heres a simplified version...

```
import ConfigParser

class read_conf_values():
    parser = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    parser.read('configuration.conf')
    a = parser.get('asection', 'a')


def confwrite(newconfig):
    file = open("configuration.conf", "w")
    file.write(newconfig)
    file.close()

conf = read_conf_values()
print conf.a
newvalue = raw_input('Enter a new value for a?')
newconfig = '[asection]\na = '+newvalue
confwrite(newconfig)
conf = read_conf_values()
print conf.a
```

I have to write the file instead of using configparser to add values as the actual configuration doesn't have sections. I can read it with a fake section module but I have to write it like a text file. This example has the same problem though.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. That's about as much detail as I can go into until you provide a [mcve] of your existing implementation.

Comment: Ok i'll get right on it :-)

Comment: Are you using configparser?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my question to explain more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `a` is a class attribute, so it is only created once, at the time you define the class.  Do this instead:

```
class read_conf_values(object):
    def __init__(self):
        parser = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        parser.read('configuration.conf')
        self.a = parser.get('asection', 'a')
```

Then a new `a` attribute will be set every time you create an instance (with `read_conf_values()`).  You can find many, many other questions on this site about the difference between class and instance attributes.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly. I have a lot to learn about classes.